# How can I simplify a giant =OR() statement that I have

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Over the years I have been adding to a function that is inserted to the right of a cell to tell if the string that cell is the name of a person or company. It is now a 4 page long google document.

The structure is this `=OR( ISNUMBER( SEARCH("LLC", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CORPORATION", A2)),  ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COMPANY", A2)),  ISNUMBER(SEARCH("HOLDINGS", A2)),  ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PARTNERS", A2)),  ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EQUITY", A2)), ...)`

I've tried listing them in the {Item|Item2|Item2|...} format i've seen but it doesn't work.

If true is returned I know it's a company name.

The function works great but I feel like there must be some way to really simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?i)LLC|CORPORATION|COMPANY|HOLDINGS|PARTNERS|EQUITY")
```

#### Reference:

- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)

Comment: It does thanks! I also have statements at the end of it that are like isnumber(search( " LP", right(A2,3))),isnumber(search(" JT/RS",right(A2,6))),....

There are a lot of them. is there any way to group them by # of characters from the right (or in some cases left) that are being searched.

Comment: So, like matching the end of the string (after a space)  or the beginning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503199/how-can-i-simplify-statements-like-these-in-an-or-statement

Comment: Posted question here with more detail, you can get more points that way too.

Comment: What is the (?i) in the regex formula?

Comment: (?i) makes the search case insensitive.