# How can I simplify statements like these in an =OR() statement?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

```
isnumber(search("-tr",right(j2,3
))),isnumber(search("-trus",right(j2,5))),isnumber(search(" ll",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" homes",right(j2,6))),isnumber(search("the ",left(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" hoa",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search("b ch",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" ch",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search("-trs",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" prop",right(j2,5))),isnumber(search(" st",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" av",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" ave",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" servi",right(j2,6))),isnumber(search(" maint",right(j2,6))),isnumber(search(" home",right(j2,5))),isnumber(search(" tr",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" assn",right(j2,5))),isnumber(search(" co",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" trus",right(j2,5))),isnumber(search(" trs",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search("-trs",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" tru",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search("jtrs",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" est of",right(j2,7))),isnumber(search(" trs",right(j2,4))),isnumber(value(LEFT(j2,1))),isnumber(search(" apts",right(j2,5))),isnumber(value(right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" grp",right(j2,4))),isnumber(value(left(right(j2,4),1))),isnumber(search(" mgmt",right(j2,5))),isnumber(search(" props",right(j2,6))),isnumber(search(" tr",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" dev",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" tr",right(j2,3))),isnumber(search(" fdn",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" ent",right(j2,4))),isnumber(search(" PRPTS",right(j2,6))),isnumber(search(" ARPTS",right(j2,6))),isnumber(search(" univ",right(j2,5)))
```

So I have this giant =OR() statement containing a bunch of isnumner(search() statements checking to see if the string in a cell ends in these phrases. It is for the purpose of identifying company names in lists that contain both peoples names and company names. I feel like there must be a more efficient way. Adding them all together in one isnumber(search() in this format {item1|item2|item3} does not work.

I feel like there must be a more efficient way.

Comment: What data do you process? Do you have an example?

Comment: Strings containing either the name of a company or person. any of those statements returning true will make the value true. My question pertains more to syntax though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502453/how-can-i-simplify-a-giant-or-statement-that-i-have/66502906#66502906), matching the end of the string can be done by using the $-sign (which means 'end of the string in regular expressions). Matching the beginning of the string on the other hand is done by providing a pattern after a caret (^), indicating the beginning of a string.

So, if you'd want to add both the the formula provided in the other thread

- (LP|JT/RS)$ : match LP OR JT/RS at the end of the string
- ^(ABC|DEF) : match ABC OR DEF at the beginning of the string

That would make the formula look something like:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?i)LLC|CORPORATION|COMPANY|HOLDINGS|PARTNERS|EQUITY|(LP|JT/RS)$|^(ABC|DEF)")
```

REFERENCE:

- [REGEXMATCH()](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/regexmatch-function-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=The%20REGEXMATCH%20function%20belongs%20to,FALSE%20if%20it%20doesn%27t.)
- [RE2 SYNTAX](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: Ok so lets say I want to search from beginning of string for some of them and end of string for others, how would I structure that?

Comment: I have given an example for that in the formula. Group the patterns you want to search for at the end of the string and separate them with a pipe ("|", which means 'or' in regex): (pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)$.  Do the same for the patterns you want to match at the beginning of the string. Separate both "groups" with a pipe ("|").